# What role to use for being able to push to container registry

Tags: google-console-developer, google-cloud-iam

API & Services” > “Credentials”Select “Create credentials” > “Services Account Key” > “Create New Services Account”.

What Role, to get storage.buckets.get?

I just need to be able to push to `gcr.io/<project>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official GCP documentation [**article**](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control#permissions_and_roles) on configuring access control for the Container Registry, you need a **Storage Admin** role for the **storage.buckets.get** permission.

Comment: I found it using the super nice filtering in roles ;-)